# I am debugging this C++ program. There are no more syntax errors that compiler shows, but there are hidden logical errors

Tags: c++, debugging

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

const int N = 20;

int main ()
{
        //Declare variables
    int counter;    //loop control variable 
    int number;     //variable to store the new number 

    int zeros = 0;                                  //Step 1 
    int odds = 0;                                   //Step 1
    int evens = 0;                                  //Step 1 
    int positives = 0;
    int negatives = 0;

  // Display Program Intro telling what the program does.  
    cout <<   "********************************************************" 
         << "\n*  This is a program that counts integers you enter as *"
         << "\n*    even, odd or zero   and     positve or negative   *"
         << "\n*  It classifies 20 numbers or use 99999 to exit early *"
         << "\n********************************************************"
         << endl;

  // Ask for 20 integers with 99999 as early exit
    cout << "\n\nPlease enter " << N << " integers, "
         << "positive, negative, or zeros."
         << "\n\t\t or enter number 99999 to exit early. \n\n"
         << endl;                                   //Step 2

    cout << "The numbers you entered are:" << endl;

  // Loop that classifies the numbers entered.
    for (counter = 1; counter <= N; counter++)      //Step 3
    {

      //  Enter number and mirror it backed on a tabbed line.
        cin >> number;                              //Step 3a
        cout << number << endl;        //Step 3b  

      //  Early exit condition:  99999        
        if(number = 99999)
           break;     // Exit loop before 20 numbers 

      //  Count Postive and Negative Numbers           
        if(number < 0)
           negatives++;
        else      
           positives++;

      //  Count Evens, Odds and Zeros           
            //Step 3c
        switch (number % 2)
        {
        case 0: 
            evens++;     
            if (number == 0)       
                zeros++;  
        case 1: 
        case -1: 
            odds++; 
        } //end switch
    } //end for loop 

    cout << endl;

  // Display the results ....  
                    //Step 4
    cout << "There are " << evens << " evens, "
         << "which includes " << zeros << " zeros."
         << endl;   
    cout << "The number of odd numbers is: " << odds
         << endl;
    cout << "The number of positive numbers is: " << positives
         << endl;
    cout << "The number of negative numbers is: " << negatives
         << endl;

  // Use Holdscreen to make sure the results are visible ....     
    char holdscr;     // This character and section is to hold screen open
    cout << "\n\n\tPress a character and Enter to exit program. ";
    cin >> holdscr;          

    return 0;
}
```

I am debugging this program. There were originally 6 errors in the program. I've found four of them as they were syntax errors. The compiler doesn't show any error but the program isn't working either.
The program is supposed to store 20 numbers and in the end tell you how many of them were even, odd, zero, negative, and positive. I am just a beginner in C++. I have tried every possible way to solve it from my side but I cannot get it to work. I have looked up every code and syntax on Google why it works that way but found no help. Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you have a debugger handy? might be nice to step through the code line by line and view variable values

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @AndyG yes, I am using it right now.

Comment: *I have looked up every code and syntax on Google* -- Learning a complex language such as C++ via Google is not recommended.

Comment: _There are no more syntax errors that compiler shows, but there are hidden logical errors_ Yes, well, that happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enable warnings when you compile then the compiler will helpfully point out certain mistakes in your code, and if it's in a good mood it may even suggest a solution:

```
<stdin>:46:23: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
            if(number = 99999)
               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
<stdin>:46:23: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
            if(number = 99999)
                      ^
               (             )
<stdin>:46:23: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
            if(number = 99999)
                      ^
```

Always compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) - it will save you a lot of time and debugging effort in the long run.

Comment: Ah, I was just about to post that as an answer.

Comment: I mostly use repl.it as it is fully online. I also use Code::Blocks. The both software show no kind of error.

Comment: @JamesStewart: that's because you haven't enabled compiler warnings (they are not generally enabled by default, unfortunately). Learn how to do this now, and save yourself a lot of time and effort in the future.

Comment: @PaulR Thank you! I will do it right now to save myself some hassle in the future.